# Count specific character in text file

Tags: python-3.x, count, character, text-files

How would I count the number of times a specific character (nonwhitespace) occurs in a text file? (i.e "," "." "a" "k" "m")

Here is what I have so far:

```
file = open("filename.txt","r")

num_char = 0
num_words = 0
num_lines = 0


for line in file:
    words = line.split()
    num_lines += 1
    num_words += len(words)
    num_char += len(line)



print ("Character count:\t" + str(num_char))
print ("Word count:\t\t" + str(num_words))
print ("Line count:\t\t" + str(num_lines))
print ("Distribution of characters: ")
```

## code for distribution so far

```
text = file.read()
file.close()
words = text.strip()
final = words.lower()
for i in range(len(words)):
    first = final.count("a")
    second = final.count("b")
print (first)
print (second)
```

This gives me my desired output for the a and b but is not very efficient to write each line of code for every character. How would I loop through for every possible character and then print out the count?

Answer (score 1):

Use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

file = open("filename.txt", "r")

num_char = 0
num_words = 0
num_lines = 0
char_distribution = Counter()

for line in file:
    words = line.split()
    num_lines += 1
    num_words += len(words)
    num_char += len(line)
    char_distribution += Counter(line.lower())

print("Character count:\t{}".format(num_char))
print("Word count:\t\t{}".format(num_words))
print("Line count:\t\t{}".format(num_lines))
print("Distribution of characters: ")
for char, count in sorted(char_distribution.items()):
    if char.isalpha() or char in ',.':
        print("\t{}\t\t{}".format(char, count))
```

Comment: This is not giving me the correct number of  individual characters for the text file. Do I need to create a new variable that has all of the whitespace removed before the initializing the count?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez, What is the expected output, and what you have got?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez, Do you want 'a' and 'A' both to count as 'a'?

Comment: yes that is why I used .lower() before initializing the for loop

Comment: Works great! How would I sort the characters? I would like it to display the , and . first and then alphabetically in ascending order from a -z

Comment: @EduardoVasquez, I changed the code. [Accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).